# How to get screen command to indicate what screen you're looking at for ubuntu servers?

Tags: bash, shell, putty, gnu-screen

When I use the screen command in red hat it lists what screen I'm looking at in putty [image: screen command in red hat]

However when I use the screen command in ubuntu 10.04 it doesn't list what screen I'm looking at in putty.  Is there any way I can configure ubuntu 10.04 or putty to list what screen I'm looking at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is set by the `hardstatus` setting in `.screenrc`. This is taken from `/etc/screenrc` on a RHEL system:

```
# Red Hat's normal status line
hardstatus string "[screen %n%?: %t%?] %h"
```

Ubuntu also has a package called `screen-profiles` (based on byobu) which contains a set of customisations for `screen`.

Answer (score 2):

Not to discredit the answer above me, the following creates something like a "taskbar" at the bottom of your screen:

```
hardstatus alwayslastline
hardstatus string '%{= BG}[ %{C}%H %{g}][%= %{=kw}%?%-Lw%?%{r}(%{W}%n*%f%t%?(%u)%?%{r})%{y}%?%+Lw%?%?%= %{g}][%{Y}%Y-%m-%d %{W}%c %{g}]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do something similar:

Put this into your ~/.screenrc:

```
termcapinfo xterm 'hs:ts=\E]2;:fs=\007:ds=\E]2;screen\007'
```

And something like this into your ~/.bashrc:

```
PS1="\[\033]0;\h [screen: ${STY#*.}]\007\]\e[1m\u@\h["${STY#*.}"]:\w \$ \e[0m"
```

(related: https://serverfault.com/a/96324/75874)

Comment: Hmm, i tried this and it didn't work =(